# Debian Linux Bridge Mode not forwarding

Tags: linux, debian, linux-networking, bridge

I am trying to bridge LAN adaptor eth0 with the eth1 interface exposed by sierra wireless LTE modem.

When I create a bridge using the following commands:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
```

Then I bring up the `br0` interface.

`brctl show` shows that bridge is up and running and ports are set to forwarding mode:

```
br0
 bridge id              8000.e0699577868f
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f
 root port                 0                    path cost                  0
 max age                  20.00                 bridge max age            20.00
 hello time                2.00                 bridge hello time          2.00
 forward delay            15.00                 bridge forward delay      15.00
 ageing time             300.01
 hello timer               0.64                 tcn timer                  0.00
 topology change timer     0.00                 gc timer                  15.64
 flags


eth0 (1)
 port id                8001                    state                forwarding
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f       path cost                  4
 designated bridge      8000.e0699577868f       message age timer          0.00
 designated port        8001                    forward delay timer        0.00
 designated cost           0                    hold timer                 0.00
 flags

eth1 (2)
 port id                8002                    state                forwarding
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f       path cost                100
 designated bridge      8000.e0699577868f       message age timer          0.00
 designated port        8002                    forward delay timer        0.00
 designated cost           0                    hold timer                 0.00
 flags
```

However as soon as the first packet is sent via the bridge to eth1, I see that the forwarding status of eth1 changes automatically to disabled.

```
br0
 bridge id              8000.e0699577868f
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f
 root port                 0                    path cost                  0
 max age                  20.00                 bridge max age            20.00
 hello time                2.00                 bridge hello time          2.00
 forward delay            15.00                 bridge forward delay      15.00
 ageing time             300.01
 hello timer               0.64                 tcn timer                  0.00
 topology change timer     0.00                 gc timer                  15.64
 flags


eth0 (1)
 port id                8001                    state                forwarding
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f       path cost                  4
 designated bridge      8000.e0699577868f       message age timer          0.00
 designated port        8001                    forward delay timer        0.00
 designated cost           0                    hold timer                 0.00
 flags

eth1 (2)
 port id                8002                    state                   disabled
 designated root        8000.e0699577868f       path cost                100
 designated bridge      8000.e0699577868f       message age timer          0.00
 designated port        8002                    forward delay timer        0.00
 designated cost           0                    hold timer                 0.00
 flags
```

Kindly let me know how to debug this issue and if we can use logging to identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to STP or maybe promiscuous mode BUT it depend on your device where you are installing your Server/Client.

Regards

Comment: Would you mind expanding a little on how STP or promiscuous mode might be involved, and how the problem can be solved?